# How to get POST variables in Python, when using gevent?

Tags: python, post, gevent

This is the question:How to get POST variables in Python, when using gevent?

The following is passed to the application:

```
def application(env, start_response):
```

And this is the other part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
print 'Serving on 8080...'
WSGIServer(('', 8080), application).serve_forever()
```

But env doesn't contain my POST!

Please enlighten me - where does my misunderstanding lie?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the request body `environ['wsgi.input'].read()`.

However, you're better off using a web framework to do that for you. Most of the WSGI-enabled web frameworks work well with gevent. If you need something minimal, [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-data) is nice.

Comment: Thank you, @Denis! I actually came across a code snippet over here: `,----
| #! /usr/bin/env python
|
| from bottle import Bottle
|
| app = Bottle()
| @app.route('/')
| def hello():
|     return "Hello World!"
|
| from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
| WSGIServer(('', 8000), app).serve_forever() `

But I don't really get what it does. And which way is faster? wsgi.input or bottle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code of request handler:

def

```
callback(request): 
    post_data = request.input_buffer.read(-1)
```

Comment: How is _request_ passed to the method? Wouldn't it be the same as env, in my case?